# if-else conditions depending on previous value

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to create a vector `z` which contains only 1 or -1.  If 1 or -1 is needed depends on the Value of RSI:

> If RSI is greater than 70, z should be -1
>   If RSI is less than 30, z should be 1

For all other cases: `z` should have the same number as the previous `z`.
That means `z = z(t-1)`

RSI is a vector containing numbers between 0 and 100. So far I have used the `ifelse` condition.

```
rsi <- RSI(YENDOL, n=14)

z <- 0

z <- ifelse(rsi >= 70,-1,z)
z <- ifelse(rsi <= 30,1,z)
```

With this I have created a `z` vector containing 0, 1 and -1. The next step would be to change the zeros into 1 or -1 depending on the previous value `(z t-1)`. That is the point where I'm stuck. I need the vector later on to multiply it with another vector.

Comment: You get the indexes of the `0`s with `idx <- which(z == 0)`. From there, you can reference previous values using e.g. `z[idx] <- ifelse(rsi[idx-1] >= 70,-1, 0)`. (Would throw an error for the first value having 0, because there's no index idex-1=0-1-=-1).

Comment: You could also consider using the `lag` function from package dplyr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `na.locf` from `zoo` package, example:

```
library(zoo)

#data
set.seed(123)
rsi <- round(runif(10,0,100))
rsi
#[1] 29 79 41 88 94  5 53 89 55 46

#apply condition to set -1 and 1
z <- ifelse(rsi >= 70,-1, ifelse(rsi <= 30,1,NA))
z
#[1]  1 -1 NA -1 -1  1 NA -1 NA NA

#Then use zoo function to fill in the NAs with previous non NA value
z <- na.locf(z)
z
#[1]  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1
```